# Is it possible to pull in all styles from external style sheets and put them on the same page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

Is it possible with javascript or jQuery to pull in all CSS rules that are listed in external files, then do `$('link').remove()`, then put all the CSS rules in style blocks on the same page?

To clarify: I want to move all external CSS rules into inline style blocks in the page with JavaScript, yes.

If so, how might I go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've left out the details about appending the rules as "inline" rules. That should be fairly trivial. Also, you'll see below I have DISABLED the style sheets rather than actually removing them. the important thing I want to hilight is that this solution allows for stylesheets that import *other* stylesheets.

**TEST.HTML**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" href="screen.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" href="screen2.css">
    </body>
    <script>
            function processSheet(sheet){
                if (sheet.cssRules){
                    for (var i=0; i< sheet.cssRules.length; i++){
                            if (sheet.cssRules[i].type == 3){
                                processSheet(sheet.cssRules[i].styleSheet);
                            }
                            else{
                                alert(sheet.cssRules[i].cssText);
                            }
                    }                               
                }
            }

            for (var i=0; i< document.styleSheets.length; i++){
                processSheet(document.styleSheets[i]);
            }

            for (var i=0; i< document.styleSheets.length; i++){
                processSheet(document.styleSheets[i].disabled=true);
            }   

    </script>

    <div>Hi</div>
</html>
```

**screen.css**

```
@import url("reset.css");
table {
    background-color:green;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you could do something like:

```
var $stylesheets = $("head link[rel=stylesheet]"),
    $style = $('<style>').appendTo('head');

$stylesheets.each(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    $.get(href, function(data) {
        $style.append(data);
    });
});

$stylesheets.remove();
```

Keep in mind that this will screw up relative paths to images/fonts in loaded stylesheets.